# How to add posts to custom menus?

Tags: theme-development, menus

I'm just beginning to work the "Custom Menu" functionality that was introduced in 3.0 into my theme.

I like everything about this new capability and API, with one exception: Why no posts?

I can create menus containing pages, categories, even tags, but where is the posts selector?

I know I could use the "Custom Links" tool as a workaround, by pasting in the URL to a given post, but I'd rather not expect my users to do that without creating a ton of support issues.

I'd rather just add a menu box called "Posts" that has the same functionality as "Pages". Has anyone done this and if so can you share the code?

Alternately, and I know I'm dreaming on this one, what about a single box with tabs for selecting between pages and posts?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

OK, I found the answer to this one and its surprisingly simple but maddeningly frustrating at the same time.

All you have to do is click "Screen Options" while viewing the "Custom Menu" manager and place a check beside "Posts" to show the elusive hidden "Posts" widget.

Now you can add "Posts" to your custom menus. Who knew anyone would ever want to do that?

Why this is not part of the default screen options, while "Tags" is, escapes me, but that's the default none the less.

Also, just to get a few more bytes out of this rant..

Whoever decided that "Excerpt" should no longer be visible on the post editor screen should have to answer at least one of the 5 emails I get per day with on the topic of "What happened to the excerpt field, it was there, now its gone". Brilliant.

Comment: that screen options button was more hidden than osama bin laden.